# R: (Selectively) Trimming the Results of a Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, iteration, decision-tree

I am using the R programming language. I am learning how to iteratively loop a procedure (e.g. generate some random data and fit different decision trees). In a previous question ([R: Saving the Results of a Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976284/r-saving-the-results-of-a-loop/65976856#65976856)), I learned how to generate random data, fit different decision trees and record their accuracies:

```
library(caret)
library(rpart)

#generate data

a = rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
b = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
c = rnorm(1000, 5, 10)
group <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
group_1 <- 1:1000

#put data into a frame
d = data.frame(a,b,c, group, group_1)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)

e <- d
vec1 <- sample(200:300, 5)
vec2 <- sample(400:500,5)
vec3 <- sample(700:800,5)
z <- 0
df <- expand.grid(vec1, vec2, vec3)
df$Accuracy <- NA

for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
  for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {
    for (k in seq_along(vec3)) {
      # d <- e
      d$group_2 = as.integer(ifelse(d$group_1 < vec1[i] , 0, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec1[i]  & d$group_1 < vec2[j] , 1, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec2[j]  & d$group_1 < vec3[k] , 2,3))))
      
      d$group_2 = as.factor(d$group_2)
      
      fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
        method = "repeatedcv",
        number = 2,
        ## repeated ten times
        repeats = 1)
      
      TreeFit <- train(group_2 ~ ., data = d[,-5],
                       method = "rpart",
                       trControl = fitControl)
      
      pred <- predict(
        TreeFit,
        d[,-5])
      
      con <- confusionMatrix(
        d$group_2,
        pred) 
      
      #update results into table
      #final_table[i,j] = con$overall[1]
      z <- z + 1
      df$Accuracy[z] <- con$overall[1]
    }
  }
}
#view the final results
head(df)
```

The data frame "df" contains the final results. My concern is: if you want to iterate this loop for many times, the size of "df" will become very large. Suppose I wanted to only keep the "top 20 rows" of  "df" (based on descending values of `df$Accuracy`). I could accomplish this as follows:

```
#sort "df" by (descending values of) "Accuracy":
df_sort <- df[order(-df$Accuracy),]

#select first 20 rows
df_final = df_sort[1:20,]
```

But I fear that limitations in computer memory could prevent "df" from being created (for large numbers of iterations).

My question: Is there a way to stop "df" from ever reaching more than 20 rows? E.g.

1. Populate first 20 rows of "df"
2. If the 21st row has a smaller accuracy than any of the previous 20 rows, then delete
3. If the 21st row has a larger accuracy than the smallest accuracy within the previous 20 rows, then keep the 21st row and delete the row with the smallest accuracy

This way, the size of "df" never grows past 20 rows.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the logic like this :

```
library(caret)
library(rpart)

a = rnorm(1000, 10, 10)
b = rnorm(1000, 10, 5)
c = rnorm(1000, 5, 10)
group <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.5,0.5))
group_1 <- 1:1000

#put data into a frame
d = data.frame(a,b,c, group, group_1)
d$group = as.factor(d$group)

e <- d
vec1 <- sample(200:300, 5)
vec2 <- sample(400:500,5)
vec3 <- sample(700:800,5)
z <- 0
#Intialise a list
result <- vector('list', 20)

for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
  for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {
    for (k in seq_along(vec3)) {
      # d <- e
      d$group_2 = as.integer(ifelse(d$group_1 < vec1[i] , 0, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec1[i]  & d$group_1 < vec2[j] , 1, ifelse(d$group_1 >vec2[j]  & d$group_1 < vec3[k] , 2,3))))
      
      d$group_2 = as.factor(d$group_2)
      
      fitControl <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
        method = "repeatedcv",
        number = 2,
        ## repeated ten times
        repeats = 1)
      
      TreeFit <- train(group_2 ~ ., data = d[,-5],
                       method = "rpart",
                       trControl = fitControl)
      
      pred <- predict(
        TreeFit,
        d[,-5])
      
      con <- confusionMatrix(
        d$group_2,
        pred) 
      
      
      z <- z + 1
      #Till 20 put the data in a list
      if(z <= 20) {
        result[[z]] <- data.frame(vec1 = vec1[i], vec2 = vec2[j], vec3 = vec3[j], Accuracy = con$overall[1])
      } else {
        #Create a dataframe of 20 list from above
        if(z == 21) result <- do.call(rbind, result)
        #Sort it in decreasing order
        result <- result[order(-result$Accuracy), ]
        #compare with last value
        if(result$Accuracy[20] < con$overall[1]) {
          #Create a new dataframe
          new_df <- data.frame(vec1 = vec1[i], vec2 = vec2[j], vec3 = vec3[j], Accuracy = con$overall[1])
          #Replace the last row
          result <- rbind(head(result, 19), new_df)
        }
      }
      
    }
  }
}
```

This should return an output similar to this :

```
result
#           vec1 vec2 vec3 Accuracy
#Accuracy2   258  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy4   258  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy9   200  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy15  214  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy16  236  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy18  207  402  706    0.376
#Accuracy11  258  414  779    0.364
#Accuracy12  200  414  779    0.364
#Accuracy6   214  414  779    0.364
#Accuracy13  236  414  779    0.364
#Accuracy10  200  402  706    0.360
#Accuracy17  214  402  706    0.360
#Accuracy3   236  402  706    0.360
#Accuracy5   207  402  706    0.360
#Accuracy19  258  414  779    0.348
#Accuracy8   200  414  779    0.348
#Accuracy7   214  414  779    0.348
#Accuracy14  236  414  779    0.348
#Accuracy    207  414  779    0.348
#Accuracy1   207  414  779    0.364
```